# How to get first Monday of Month and Week in fullcalendar control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

I have one case related to fullCalendar control. I am showing Days from Mon-Fri and there is Custom Button added named as Add new Appointment. When user clicks on this button we need to show First Monday date for Month view and if it is Week view we need to show 1st date(Monday) of that week. '

I have done this way till now it's working for IST time Zone but my client is CST/EST and it takes previous day. Example- on Month view if i go to Feb and click on Add new it should 02-02-2016 but it's taking 01-31-2015.

```
function processDateTimeForNewCalendar() {
    debugger;
    var mondayForWeek = common.getMondayForCurrentWeek(new Date());

    var dateHeader = $('div.fc-center h2').text();
    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
    var date, sTime, eTime;
    var currentDate = new Date();
    if (view.name === 'month') {
        debugger;
        var currentMonth = dateHeader.split(" ")[0];
        var currentYear = dateHeader.split(" ")[1];
        var monthInNo = common.getMonthNumberByMonthName(currentMonth);

        var temp = currentDate.getDate() + "-" + currentMonth + "-" + currentYear + " " + currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes()
        var tempDate = new Date(temp);
        var mondayForWeek = common.getMondayForCurrentWeek(tempDate);

        if ((currentDate.getMonth() + 1) === monthInNo)
            date = new Date(currentDate.getDate() + "-" + currentMonth + "-" + currentYear + " " + currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes());
        if ((currentDate.getMonth() + 1) < monthInNo || (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) > monthInNo)
            date = new Date(view.intervalStart);


        sTime = moment(date).format("hh:mm A");
        eTime = moment(date).add(30, 'minutes').format("hh:mm A");
    }
    if (view.name === 'agendaWeek' || view.name === 'agendaDay') {
        date = new Date(view.start);
        date = moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
        sTime = moment(currentDate).format("hh:mm A");
        eTime = moment(currentDate).add(30, 'minutes').format("hh:mm A");
    }
    $(CALENDAR.ApptStartDateById).val(moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
    $(CALENDAR.ApptEndDateById).val(moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
    $(CALENDAR.ApptStartTime).timepicker("setTime", sTime);
    $(CALENDAR.ApptEndTime).timepicker("setTime", eTime);

    $(CALENDAR.Duration).val(calculateDuration());
    $(CALENDAR.ApptStartDateById).datepicker("update", date).datepicker('fill');
    $(CALENDAR.ApptEndDateById).datepicker("update", date).datepicker('fill');
}
```

Please help me fix this.

Thanks,
Amod

Comment: Could you please provide us with what you've tried so far?

Comment: @ChrisBeckett - Thank you, Yes sure. Please check the question again. i have put the code there with the issue. My other concern like i am not allowing fullcalendar to use UTC so timezone:'local' is set in options. Can i turn off time zone for $('#Calendar').fullCalendar('getView') ;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('calendar selector').fullCalendar('getView').start` to get the starting date of your current view;

Comment: I have used that check the code. But i when my client is testing on his environment its picking up  -1  day i.e. for Feb it should pick 1st Monday i.e. 1 Feb 2016 but its picking up 31 Dec 2015.

Comment: And if you change it to $('calendar selector').fullCalendar('getView').start.startOf('month') ?

Comment: I checked that too but still its showing me previous date. I am thinking of getting month's first Monday and Week's first Monday and then manipulate the date.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in other way by finding the first Day of the Month and checks if it is sunday. If it is then add +1 day. Check the code below-

```
function getFirstDayOfMonth(d) {                
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth(), 1);        
        // if sunday add +1 day
        if (d.getDay() === 0)
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1, 1);
        return d;
    }
```

Hope, this is the alternate solution for finding first day of month using fullCalendar.